# CRC polynomial and Parity Error detection

Tags: detection, error, error-correction, crc, parity

My question is about the CRC generator polynomial.

If I have a generator of level 5, say:

$$X^5+X^4+X^2+1$$

**How can I know if it can or cannot detect a parity error?**

**Also how can I know the error patterns that can pass without being detected?**

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "parity error"? In its most general sense, it means any odd number (1, 3, 5, ...) of bits have been flipped.

Answer (score 2):

This is a **general rule** , in youre case  `k = 6`

- Short Burst Errors

  (Length b ≤ k, number of redundant bits)

*-->All errors up to length k are detected*

- Long Burst Errors (Length b = k+1)

Undetectable only if burst error is the same as g(x)

```
g(x) = x^k+ … + 1       k-1 bits between xk and x0 
e(x) = x^k + … + 1      must match
```

*Probability of not detecting the error is 2^(-(k-1))*

- Longer Burst Errors (Length m > k+1)

*Probability of not detecting the error is 2^(-k)*